# An intuitive explanation of the so called Galileoʼs theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

The statement of the theorem is as follows ([see Francisquini et al, Physics Education, Volume 48, Number 6, November 2013](http://www.if.ufrj.br/~pef/producao_academica/artigos/2013_mariana_1.pdf)):
Prove that the time taken for a particle to slide from the highest point, along a chord of a vertical circle is constant.

I know how to approach this problem mathematically, by constructing a diameter and then resolving the components of velocity along it. But, I am unsure as to why this really happens?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by *why this really happens*. It happens because the acceleration is lower for a chord nearer the horizontal. The decrease in the acceleration exactly balances out the decrease in the length of the chord. I don't see what more there is to say.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: @JohnRennie Could you please elaborate on your explanation.

Comment: I think you are doubting mathematics and following your common sense

Comment: No, I am not doubting math, but I just want to really understand what is going on? You know a kind of intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The closer the chord from b is to being vertical the longer the chord will be, on the other hand the closer the chord is to being vertical the steeper its gradient and the faster the bead will roll down it. Intuitively you can imagine the increased speed and increased distance "cancelling each other out".